# How to parse custom multiple Date formats in Java

Tags: java, java-time

I want to parse custom multiple Date formats in Java. Here is my code

**Scenario 1:**
**Order of patterns:**

- yyMMdd'h'HH
- yyMMdd

> DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
> .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd'h'HH"))
> .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd")).toFormatter();

**Works:**

```
String dateString1 = "201028h05";

LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString1, formatter);
```

**Doesn't works:**

```
String dateString2 = "201028";

LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString2, formatter);
```

**Scenario 2:**
**Order of patterns:**

- yyMMdd
- yyMMdd'h'HH

> DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
> .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd")).toFormatter();
> .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd'h'HH"))

**Doesn't Work:**

```
  String dateString1 = "201028h05";
    
    LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString1, formatter);
```

**Works:**

```
String dateString2 = "201028";

LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString2, formatter);
```

How to make it work for both of the date patterns irrespective of any input pattern order. I don't want to use any external dependency for this.

Comment: What if you swap the order in which you insert the patterns? From most generic to more specific (instead of more specific to most generic)?

Comment: It works if I swap the order. But input value should be matched with the first pattern, if it doesn't match, it throws error.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but the second `dateString1` does not match the pattern `yyMMdd'h'HH`, since it is missing the whole `'h'HH` component. You would need to add something of the sort `h00` to the second `dateString1` for it to be captured by the first pattern.

Comment: @npinti Update the question with scenarios

Comment: What result do you want or expect when there is no hour of day in the string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `[]` to define the optional parts within a pattern. Additionally you need to set defaults to not get an exception when no time is supplied.

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyMMdd['h'HH]")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
        .toFormatter();

String dateString1 = "201028h05";
LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString1, formatter);
System.out.println(date1);

String dateString2 = "201028";
LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString2, formatter);
System.out.println(date2);
```

*Output:*

```
2020-10-28T05:00
2020-10-28T00:00
```